# Java non greedy regex with separated groups

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I was wondering if it was possible to use non-greedy matching strategy on separated groups?

I want to match something between `<>`. For example:

```
<a href="aabbcc"> xxx </a> <a href="aabbcc"> aabbcc </a>
```

I want to get the last aabbcc, so I wrote:

```
(.*)(>.*)(?<![a-zA-Z])(aabbcc)(?![a-zA-Z])(.*<.*)
```

I wish to get and replace the last "aabbcc" between `<a>` and `</a>` and keep other groups unchanged, it worked in this case.
However, it will match aabbcc in a wrong situation. 
https://regex101.com/r/OeZDu5/1/

Could anyone tell me how to use non-greedy strategy in this case or provide me with other solutions?

Comment: And you're trying to do this in Java? Not JavaScript? Because it would make more sense in JavaScript to simply use `.innerHTML`. And an HTML parser would work better for Java.

Comment: Why not use an actual HTML parser?

Comment: Yeah, use an XML parser for this.  A regex solution would be brittle and prone to error later on.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://regex101.com/r/RiZ59e/1

Comment: Yes. I am using java. Those a tags are not in html files. They are in a config setting file where some lines contain a tag.

Comment: Regex101 does not have java regex tester. Maybe there are some subtle differences between java and php regex rules.

Comment: Then post a [mcve]. Also, what keeps you from running some of your settings through an HTML parser if they contain HTML code?

Comment: I apologize for my fault. melpomene was right. It worked on regex101.com/r/RiZ59e/1 However, I have some trouble in this case https://regex101.com/r/OeZDu5/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String replace(String s, String target, String newString) {
        String regex1 = "(.*)(<.*?>)(.*)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex1);
        Matcher matcher1 = pattern.matcher(s);
        //System.out.println(s);
        if (matcher1.matches()) {
            String tmp1 = replace(matcher1.group(1), target, newString);
            String tmp2 = replace(matcher1.group(3), target, newString);
            return tmp1 + matcher1.group(2) + tmp2;

        } else {
            String regex2a = "(.*)(?<![a-zA-Z])(";
            String regex2b = ")(?![a-zA-Z])(.*)";
            String regex2 = regex2a + target + regex2b;
            pattern = Pattern.compile(regex2);
            Matcher matcher2 = pattern.matcher(s);
            if (matcher2.matches()) {
                s = replace(matcher2.group(1),target,newString) + newString + replace(matcher2.group(3),target,newString);
            }
            return s;

        }
    }
```

Leave the group2 alone to keep strings in the <> untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
    String input = "<a href=\"aabbcc\"> xxx </a> <a href=\"aabbcc\"> aabbcc </a>\n"
        + "<a href=\"aa\">ppp</a><a href=\"yy\">zz</a>";

    System.out.println( "--input--" );
    System.out.println( input );

    String regexx = "<[^>]+>.*<[^>]+>[ ]*<[^>]+>(.*)<[^>]+>";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( regexx );
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( input );

    System.out.println( "values:" );
    while ( matcher.find() )
    {
        System.out.println( matcher.group( 1 ) );
    }
```

Hope this will help you.